# Accessing suggested actions in VS2012 using keyboard

Tags: visual-studio-2012

When I've added a reference to a class but forgot to add `using` directive, R# would suggest automatic insertion of it. I'd access that by <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>.

Now, I'm on a system without R# and that forces me to use the mouse to unfold that tiny thingy to unfold a suggestion menu. How can I do that from the keyboard? Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is to expand the ***Smart Tag*** menu.
This can be done by pressing the  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Period (.)</kbd> shortcut.

You can also use <kbd>Alt</kbd> +<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>   shortcut for this.

**Edit:**
And if by any chance the combo above doesn't work for you, you can re-activate it like this:

1 .
`Tools > Customize > Keyboard...` (notice the `Keyboard...` button is at the bottom right of that screen)

2 . Find the `View.ShowSmartTag` command and set it back to the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Period (.)</kbd> shortcut.

Comment: I'd swear that I've tried that combo... Is it activated by default? How can I (re)activate it if it's off?! (I'll try that out at the office tomorrow morning!)

Comment: Updated answer on how to reactivate it :) - Let me know if you have any more problems...

Comment: Oh, this is a golden nugget type of info. In fact, I **do** have another problem. I've noticed that there are (at least) two different types of menus like that. The other is unfoldable too but placed **at the end** of the word, instead of at the beginning. How do I access it from the keyboard? And what is the command for it in the customizations to the keyboard?

Comment: @BethLore - Sorry, couldn't find that *second* menu you were talking about. Can you by any chance add a screenshot with an example of it (preferably with the menu open) so I could better understand which one you're talking about?